# What does hostname function and HOSTNAME variable actually do

Tags: linux, networking, dns, hostname

I use hostname 'host' and domainname 'domain.com'

I set HOSTNAME env to 'user.linux'

I add test.testdns.com to 127.0.0.1 to /etc/hosts

Which one is really the hostname and domainname, and what does hostname command do actually?